# Northern Telecom SL-1 PBX Programming Language

Tags: history

My first job in 1981 was programing the Northern Telecom/ BNR SL-1 PBX. It had been licensed in the UK by GEC (the UK company, not the US one) from Northern Telecom, and I added some UK specific features. It was programed in a language called SL-1 that I believe was short for Switching Language 1. SL-1 was a high-level language that was then compiled to a byte code that was then interpreted by the CPU on the PBX. Is there a reference to the SL-1 programing language anywhere? I can find information on the SL-1 hardware and the Man-Machine interface used to configure the system, but not to the actual language that ran the PBX.

Comment: Nothing in the Internet Archive?

Comment: [Here?](https://www.academia.edu/56490827/SL1_Language_A_Specification_and_Design_Tool_for_Switching_Systems_Software_Development)

Comment: Thank you. I did look there and saw this (perhaps I should have mentioned this in my question) but t don't think that this is what the Nortel PBX used. In the article it references a different PBX, and from what I remember the Nortel SL-1 language was defined by Bell Northern Research (BNR).

Comment: SL-1 was, in my memory, the name of the switch (later "Meridian", which might increase the number of Google hits), not the name of the language.

Comment: Having "1" as a name-suffix was popular for a while. How many such ever progressed to "2"?  ;-)

Comment: @dave - OS/2 did... Not that I ever saw OS/1 mind you!

Comment: Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protel), the SL-1/Meridian switch was programmed in a language called 'Protel'.  Does that look familiar?

Comment: @JonCuster wouldn’t OS/1 have been PC-DOS?

Answer (score 1):

[Bitsavers](https://bitsavers.org/) has a large collection of old computer manuals in PDF format. They only have a few manuals for [Northern Telecom](https://bitsavers.org/pdf/northernTelecom/). For the Meridian they only have the Design Guidebook.